# how to parse a file which has more than one top level element using python

Tags: python

I have written python script for parsing a file.

python script :

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parse

import xml.dom.minidom

DOMTree = xml.dom.minidom.parse("details.xml")

CallDetailRecord = DOMTree.documentElement

def getText(data):

        detail = str(data)
        #match = re.search(r'(.*\s)(false).*|(.*\s)(true).*',detail,re.IGNORECASE)
        match_false = re.search(r'(.*\s)(false).*',detail,re.IGNORECASE)
        if (match_false):
                return match_false.group(2)
        match_true = re.search(r'(.*\s)(true).*',detail,re.IGNORECASE)
        if (match_true):
                return match_true.group(2)



org_addr = CallDetailRecord.getElementsByTagName("origAddress")

for record in org_addr:

        ton_1 = record.getElementsByTagName("ton")[0]
        npi_1 = record.getElementsByTagName("npi")[0]
        pid_1 = record.getElementsByTagName("pid")[0]
        msdn_1 = record.getElementsByTagName("msisdn")[0]
        org_ton = ton_1.childNodes[0].data
        org_npi = npi_1.childNodes[0].data
        org_pid = pid_1.childNodes[0].data
        org_msdn = msdn_1.childNodes[0].data

recp_addr = CallDetailRecord.getElementsByTagName("recipAddress")

for record in recp_addr:
        ton_1 = record.getElementsByTagName("ton")[0]
        npi_1 = record.getElementsByTagName("npi")[0]
        pid_1 = record.getElementsByTagName("pid")[0]
        msdn_1 = record.getElementsByTagName("msisdn")[0]
        rec_ton = ton_1.childNodes[0].data
        rec_npi = npi_1.childNodes[0].data
        rec_pid = pid_1.childNodes[0].data
        rec_msdn = msdn_1.childNodes[0].data

dgti_addr = CallDetailRecord.getElementsByTagName("dgtiAddress")

for record in dgti_addr:

        ton_1 = record.getElementsByTagName("ton")[0]
        npi_1 = record.getElementsByTagName("npi")[0]
        pid_1 = record.getElementsByTagName("pid")[0]
        msdn_1 = record.getElementsByTagName("msisdn")[0]
        dgti_ton = ton_1.childNodes[0].data
        dgti_npi = npi_1.childNodes[0].data
        dgti_pid = pid_1.childNodes[0].data
        dgti_msdn = msdn_1.childNodes[0].data

calling_line_id = CallDetailRecord.getElementsByTagName("callingLineId")

for record in calling_line_id:

        ton_1 = record.getElementsByTagName("ton")[0]
        npi_1 = record.getElementsByTagName("npi")[0]
        pid_1 = record.getElementsByTagName("pid")[0]
        msdn_1 = record.getElementsByTagName("msisdn")[0]
        clid_ton = ton_1.childNodes[0].data
        clid_npi = npi_1.childNodes[0].data
        clid_pid = pid_1.childNodes[0].data
        clid_msdn = msdn_1.childNodes[0].data

untransl_OrigAddress = CallDetailRecord.getElementsByTagName("untranslOrigAddress")


sub_time = CallDetailRecord.getElementsByTagName("submitTime")[0]

if(sub_time):

        sub_time_value = sub_time.childNodes[0].data
        print " \n SUBMIT TIME: %s \n" %sub_time_value

sub_date = CallDetailRecord.getElementsByTagName("submitDate")[0]

if(sub_date):

        sub_date_value = sub_date.childNodes[0].data
        print " \n SUBMIT DATE: %s\n" %sub_time_value

termin_time = CallDetailRecord.getElementsByTagName("terminTime")[0]

if(termin_time):

        termin_time_value = termin_time.childNodes[0].data
        print " \n TERMIN TIME: %s \n" %termin_time_value

termin_date = CallDetailRecord.getElementsByTagName("terminDate")[0]

if(termin_date):

        termin_date_value = termin_date.childNodes[0].data
        print " \n TERMIN DATE: %s\n" %termin_time_value

status = CallDetailRecord.getElementsByTagName("status")[0]

if(status):

        status_value = status.childNodes[0].data
        print " \n STATUS: %s\n" %status_value

msglength = CallDetailRecord.getElementsByTagName("lengthOfMessage")[0]

if(msglength):
        msglength_value = msglength.childNodes[0].data
        print " \n MESSAGE LENGTH: %s\n" %msglength_value

prioIndicator = CallDetailRecord.getElementsByTagName("prioIndicator")[0]

if (prioIndicator):

        #print prioIndicator.childNodes[0].data
        prioIndicator_value = getText(prioIndicator.childNodes[0])
        print " \n PRIO INDICATOR: %s\n" %prioIndicator_value
```

To reduce the Size, I'm not posting my entire script.

INPUT FILE:

```
<CallDetailRecord>
<origAddress>
    <ton>international</ton>
    <npi>telephone</npi>
    <pid>plmn</pid>
    <msisdn>32410000</msisdn>
 </origAddress>
 <recipAddress>
     <ton>international</ton>
    <npi>telephone</npi>
         <pid>plmn</pid>
         <msisdn>918337807718</msisdn>
 </recipAddress>
 <submitDate>14-08-20</submitDate>
 <submitTime>19:36:29</submitTime>
 <status>deleted</status>
 <terminDate>14-08-23</terminDate>
 <terminTime>19:51:52</terminTime>
 <lengthOfMessage>38</lengthOfMessage>
 <prioIndicator><false/></prioIndicator>
 <deferIndicator><true/></deferIndicator>
 <notifIndicator><false/></notifIndicator>
 <recipIntlMobileSubId>26204487</recipIntlMobileSubId>
 <callingLineId>
     <ton>international</ton>
         <npi>telephone</npi>
         <pid>plmn</pid>
         <msisdn>32410000</msisdn>
 </callingLineId>
 <smsContentDcs>0</smsContentDcs>
 <messageReference>13</messageReference>
 <deliveryAttempts>151</deliveryAttempts>
 <untranslOrigAddress>
     <ton>international</ton>
         <npi>telephone</npi>
         <pid>plmn</pid>
         <msisdn>32410000</msisdn>
 </untranslOrigAddress>
 <tpDCS>0</tpDCS>
 <genericUrgencyLevel>bulk</genericUrgencyLevel>
 <teleserviceId>4098</teleserviceId>
 <recipNetworkType>gsm</recipNetworkType>
 <rbdlFlags1>
     10000000000000000000000000000000
 </rbdlFlags1>
 </CallDetailRecord>
```

Script works fine for this file. But suppose consider I have more than one
   CallDetailRecord>, then how to parse that file.

EXAMPLE:

```
<CallDetailRecord>
    .
    .
    .
</CallDetailRecord>
<CallDetailRecord>
    .
    . 
    .
</CallDetailRecord>
<CallDetailRecord>
    .
    .
    .
</CallDetailRecord>
```

Hopefully waiting for some good results :)!!!

Comment: That is a huge code dump. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use wrapper class to parse this file. Wrap your file which contains multiple top elements into a wrapper like this

< wrapper>

```
   #your file
```

< /wrapper>

and then start parsing the file with the root element . The parser will construct a document with a root element wrapper containing all the elements that were in the file.